# Цикл While. Как написать программу с его использованием по заданию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while

Прошу подсказки как решить задачу. В самом начале изучения Python завис на задаче с циклом WHILE.
Не пойму как выводить сумму разных итераций можно. Примеры были с конкретным условием выполнения цикла до сих пор (например while j < 10:). А здесь задача по итогу урока с другим условием:

**"1) Напишите программу, которая будет принимать числа от пользователя и суммировать их, пока он не напишет слово «sum».
2) Когда пользователь напишет слово «sum», должна быть выведена сумма всех чисел и начат процесс заново."**

Понимаю что нужно использовать while True  и break но сегодня не идёт ничего выходит:

```py
r = 0
while True:
    num = float(input('Ваше число:', ))
    r = r + num
    print('Cумма',  r)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = 0
while True:
    var_input = input("number input: ")
    if var_input == "sum":
        print("result", result)
        result = 0
        continue

    result += int(var_input)
```

Comment: @nomnoms12 Благодарю! Надо разобраться как это (код по задаче) работает